# Recurring Boolean field in Redis json key value breaks document in index

Tags: json, redis, boolean, tags

I have this json document that i cant search for if i include the boolean field APurchaseNeed (as TAG) to the index. Its breaking when the field APurchaseNeed is present on two or more nodes in the ACompanies array. If only one ACompany node includes an APurchaseNeed, the document can be found in a search.

So am i missing some special way to index TAG when there are multiple nodes in the same document?
It's working as expected with NUMERIC and TEXT, but not with TAG.

This is the json document that i would like to index and search for:

```
{
    "TypeId": 1,
    "ACompanies": [
        {
            "ACompanyId": 100,
            "APurchaseNeed": false
        },
        {
            "ACompanyId": 200,
            "APurchaseNeed": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Steps to reproduce, tested in a clean db on a Redis Cloud free account (RedisJson v2.4.7, RedisSearch v.20612)

Add the document to Redis:

`JSON.SET TESTKEY "$" "{ \"TypeId\":1, \"ACompanies\": [ { \"ACompanyId\": 100, \"APurchaseNeed\": false }, { \"ACompanyId\": 200, \"APurchaseNeed\": false } ] } ] }"`

Create the index, without the problematic field:

`FT.CREATE idxTest ON JSON SCHEMA "$.TypeId" as TypeId NUMERIC "$.ACompanies.*.ACompanyId" as ACompanyId NUMERIC`

Do a search, the document is found as expected:

`FT.SEARCH idxTest "@TypeId:[1 1] @ACompanyId:[100 100]"`

Drop the index:

`FT.DROPINDEX idxTest`

Recreate the index, now adding the boolean field as a TAG:

`FT.CREATE idxTest ON JSON SCHEMA "$.TypeId" as TypeId NUMERIC "$.ACompanies.*.ACompanyId" as ACompanyId NUMERIC "$.ACompanies.*.APurchaseNeed" as APurchaseNeed TAG`

Do the same search as before, but now i get nothing back:

`FT.SEARCH idxTest "@TypeId:[1 1] @ACompanyId:[100 100]"`

So how do i add the field APurchaseNeed to the index, so that i then can do something like?:

`FT.SEARCH idxTest "@TypeId:[1 1] @APurchaseNeed:{false}"`

**Works with one node, but not with two.**

As i mentioned in the begining, if only one of the nodes in the array contains APurchaseNeed, then i can search for it, but thats not what i want, i need a way to make it work even with two or more nodes with the boolean field.

Steps to reproduce it working with only one node containing the boolean field (ACompanyId:200 is missing APurchaseNeed here):

`JSON.SET TESTKEY "$" "{ \"TypeId\":1, \"ACompanies\": [ { \"ACompanyId\": 100, \"APurchaseNeed\": false }, { \"ACompanyId\": 200 } ] } ] }"`

And now if we search again, we get the document back:

`FT.SEARCH idxTest "@TypeId:[1 1] @ACompanyId:[100 100]"`

And when only one node has APurchaseNeed i can search on the TAG.

`FT.SEARCH idxTest "@TypeId:[1 1] @APurchaseNeed:{false}"`

**How do i index the field APurchaseNeed to be able to search for it (or anything) and not break the index for the document when there are multiple nodes with APurchaseNeed?**